# Centering between two anchors

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, anchor

I want to set a `centerYAnchor` between two anchors. Similar to this:

```
centeredLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
```

However, I don't want it to be centered relative to the screen. I want it to be right in between two other anchors on the screen. Like if I have a toolbar at the top like this:

```
toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
```

Then I have a button at the bottom like this:

```
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
```

is there a way I can center `centeredLabel`'s y constraint to be right between the bottomanchor of `toolbar` and the top anchor of `button`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a way I can center centeredLabel's y constraint to be right between the bottomanchor of toolbar and the top anchor of button?

Yes, there is. The simple way is to use a transparent spacer view whose top is anchored to the upper anchor and whose bottom is anchored to the lower anchor. Now you center-anchor your label to the center of the spacer view.

However, although that is simple, it is not the *best* way. The best way is to create, instead of a transparent spacer view, a custom [UILayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide). Unfortunately this can be done only in code, not in the storyboard (whereas the spacer view and label can be configured entirely in the storyboard). But it has the advantage that it doesn't burden the rendering tree with an additional view.

Here's your situation, more or less, using a button as the upper view and a button as the lower view. The label is centered vertically between them:

[image]

Here's the code that generated that situation. `b1` and `b2` are the buttons (and it doesn't matter how they are created and positioned):

```
    let g = UILayoutGuide()
    self.view.addLayoutGuide(g)
    g.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b1.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    g.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b2.topAnchor).isActive = true
    g.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:b1.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    g.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:b1.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    let lab = UILabel()
    lab.text = "Label"
    lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(lab)
    lab.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:g.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    lab.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:g.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Cool! I was going to show you the storyboard solution in detail, but you'll find that UILayoutGuide is just what you're looking for. It is a view-like set of anchors with no actual view. As the docs say, "Use layout guides to replace the dummy views you may have created to represent inter-view spaces or encapsulation in your user interface." That is just what you would have had, an "inter-view space".

Comment: What do you think about putting the view in a stack view and having a stack above and below the stack that has the view? Then set the bottom stack to be equal in height to the top stack to center things? Is that good too? Or is the layout guide better?

Answer (score 2):

Although [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283567/4698501)'s solution works, here is a simpler one that uses autolayout without the need to create a UILayoutGuide.

iOS 10 introduced a simple way of doing this through `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to:)` and `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to:)`.

Here are convenience methods which wrap up this logic.

For X axis centering

```
extension NSLayoutXAxisAnchor {
    func constraint(between anchor1: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, and anchor2: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        let anchor1Constraint = anchor1.anchorWithOffset(to: self)
        let anchor2Constraint = anchorWithOffset(to: anchor2)
        return anchor1Constraint.constraint(equalTo: anchor2Constraint)
    }
}
```

For Y axis centering

```
extension NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    func constraint(between anchor1: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, and anchor2: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        let anchor1Constraint = anchor1.anchorWithOffset(to: self)
        let anchor2Constraint = anchorWithOffset(to: anchor2)
        return anchor1Constraint.constraint(equalTo: anchor2Constraint)
    }
}
```

To do what you need you can call:

```
centeredLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(between: toolbar.bottomAnchor, and: button.topAnchor)
```